# Error when retrieving JSON from PHP using JQuery/AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, jquery

I am trying to learn how to build an image gallery on a website. I am creating the page using **.html** / **.css** / **.js** files. I also have an image folder on the web server that has an arbitrary number of images in it. My goal is to inject **img** tags containing each of those images URL's from that folder into the *photos* **div** in my html.

I wrote the following **php script** which I also have on the server:

```
<?php
    $imagesDir = '../images/art/';
    $images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
    echo json_encode($images);
?>
```

I realize I could generate the entire html through a php script and bypass the AJAX, however I don't want to do that as learning is my primary objective here and I want to learn how to interact with php through AJAX.

The **output of the php script** when I visit the URL (http://www.fakedomain.com/php/images.php) in the web browser is of the following form:

```
[
    "../images/art/art01.jpg",
    "../images/art/art02.jpg",
    "../images/art/art03.jpg",
    "../images/art/art04.jpg"
]
```

I am then trying to make an AJAX call in my javascript to retrieve the JSON from the php file.

```
$.getJSON('http://www.fakedomain.com/php/images.php', function(images) {
            $.each(images, function(i, image) {
                $("#photos").append("<a class='fancybox' rel='group' src='" + image + "'/><img  src='" + image + "'/></a>");
            });
        });
```

Although this seems like it should be very straightforward from other posts I've seen, I get errors and it appears that no code executes within the callback function. I've even just tried calling the javascript below directly in the Chrome Javascript console while on the page and I get a longwinded error.

**Entered into Chrome Javascript console**:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.domain.com/php/images.php', function(images) { console.log("test") });
```

**Longwinded error**:

```
Object {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
abort: function (e){var t=e||T;return l&&l.abort(t),k(0,t),this}
always: function (){return i.done(arguments).fail(arguments),this}
complete: function (){if(u){var t=u.length;(function i(t){b.each(t,function(t,n){var r=b.type(n);"function"===r?e.unique&&p.has(n)||u.push(n):n&&n.length&&"string"!==r&&i(n)})})(arguments),n?o=u.length:r&&(s=t,c(r))}return this}
done: function (){if(u){var t=u.length;(function i(t){b.each(t,function(t,n){var r=b.type(n);"function"===r?e.unique&&p.has(n)||u.push(n):n&&n.length&&"string"!==r&&i(n)})})(arguments),n?o=u.length:r&&(s=t,c(r))}return this}
error: function (){if(u){var t=u.length;(function i(t){b.each(t,function(t,n){var r=b.type(n);"function"===r?e.unique&&p.has(n)||u.push(n):n&&n.length&&"string"!==r&&i(n)})})(arguments),n?o=u.length:r&&(s=t,c(r))}return this}
fail: function (){if(u){var t=u.length;(function i(t){b.each(t,function(t,n){var r=b.type(n);"function"===r?e.unique&&p.has(n)||u.push(n):n&&n.length&&"string"!==r&&i(n)})})(arguments),n?o=u.length:r&&(s=t,c(r))}return this}
getAllResponseHeaders: function (){return 2===x?a:null}
getResponseHeader: function (e){var t;if(2===x){if(!c){c={};while(t=Tn.exec(a))c[t[1].toLowerCase()]=t[2]}t=c[e.toLowerCase()]}return null==t?null:t}
overrideMimeType: function (e){return x||(p.mimeType=e),this}
pipe: function (){var e=arguments;return b.Deferred(function(n){b.each(t,function(t,o){var a=o[0],s=b.isFunction(e[t])&&e[t];i[o[1]](function(){var e=s&&s.apply(this,arguments);e&&b.isFunction(e.promise)?e.promise().done(n.resolve).fail(n.reject).progress(n.notify):n[a+"With"](this===r?n.promise():this,s?[e]:arguments)})}),e=null}).promise()}
progress: function (){if(u){var t=u.length;(function i(t){b.each(t,function(t,n){var r=b.type(n);"function"===r?e.unique&&p.has(n)||u.push(n):n&&n.length&&"string"!==r&&i(n)})})(arguments),n?o=u.length:r&&(s=t,c(r))}return this}
promise: function (e){return null!=e?b.extend(e,r):r}
readyState: 0
responseText: ""
setRequestHeader: function (e,t){var n=e.toLowerCase();return x||(e=v[n]=v[n]||e,y[e]=t),this}
state: function (){return n}
status: 0
statusCode: function (e){var t;if(e)if(2>x)for(t in e)m[t]=[m[t],e[t]];else N.always(e[N.status]);return this}
statusText: "error"
success: function (){if(u){var t=u.length;(function i(t){b.each(t,function(t,n){var r=b.type(n);"function"===r?e.unique&&p.has(n)||u.push(n):n&&n.length&&"string"!==r&&i(n)})})(arguments),n?o=u.length:r&&(s=t,c(r))}return this}
then: function (){var e=arguments;return b.Deferred(function(n){b.each(t,function(t,o){var a=o[0],s=b.isFunction(e[t])&&e[t];i[o[1]](function(){var e=s&&s.apply(this,arguments);e&&b.isFunction(e.promise)?e.promise().done(n.resolve).fail(n.reject).progress(n.notify):n[a+"With"](this===r?n.promise():this,s?[e]:arguments)})}),e=null}).promise()}
__proto__: Object
```

I would greatly appreciate any help. I've read through many similar StackOverflow posts and tried their solutions with no success. I feel like I must be missing something basic here.

Thank you very much for taking the time to assist.

**EDIT:**

Arun's comment letting me know that I needed to be calling the php script from the same domain was the clue that led me towards fixing this issue by deploying my code to the web server where the php script already was. Even then I had an error when my AJAX called the php script using an absolute path. Once I switched to using a relative path, it worked fine. Any ideas why?

Comment: Can you go into Chrome developer tools, look at the list of network requests and see the response? Does anything look suspicious there?

Comment: i think cross domain request is the probs..

Comment: Everything else on the page loads fine but this request does look suspicious. I see Name: images.php, Method: GET, Status: (canceled), Type: Pending, Initiator: jquery-latest.min.js:5 Script, Size: 13B 0B, Time: 2.29s -

Comment: Arun, I think that makes perfect sense. I am currently working with the website in Dreamweaver and am previewing it locally on my computer while the php script is actually deployed onto the web server. I guess I need to preview with the php script local on my computer? EDIT: As I said, I am new to php. Am I able to run the script locally...?

Comment: Your debug code should be more like: $.getJSON('http://www.domain.com/php/images.php', function(images) { console.log(images) }); That way it will output anything PHP is outputing, including errors if enabled.

Comment: I went ahead and deployed the gallery onto the web server under the same domain as the php script. Using this debug code from the Chrome Javascript console I got the array as a response! `$.getJSON('/php/images.php', function(images) { console.log(images) });` I then tried using the relative path to the php script in my real javascript instead of the absolute path and it worked fine!

Comment: @ArunKillu Thanks for the tip. Your comment led me down the path to getting this working correctly! Am I able to accept a comment as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding

```php
header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
```

before the `echo` statement in the PHP script.

Comment: I tried adding it and I got the same error. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

There was a 2 part solution to my problem. I believe the root cause was that my php script was on a different domain than the site I was trying to call it from using AJAX (*php script was on my web server while I was still testing the site locally*).

1. I had was testing my site locally with my php script running serverside. As @ArunKillu mentioned in his comment, the cross domain request was causing my AJAX call to the php script to fail. Once I had deployed my site onto the same domain as the php script, that was no longer a problem.
2. I don't know why, but as long as I specified an absolute path to the php script from my AJAX call, it would fail. I assume this relates to ensuring the request is from the same domain. Once I switched to using a relative path to call the php script, I had no issues.

Thanks for the help everyone who participated in this discussion.